# Zero Fill Data for Missing Dates

Tags: sql, netezza

I have two tables:

```
Cust    Sales   Week
123     4       1/8/2015
123     3       1/22/2015
234     4       1/1/2015
```

.

```
Week
1/1/2015
1/8/2015
1/15/2015
1/22/2015
```

I want to combine them so that every Cust has every date and where there are no Sales it is filled with 0.

```
Cust    Sales   Week
123     4       1/1/2015
123     0       1/8/2015
123     0       1/15/2015
123     3       1/22/2015
234     4       1/1/2015
234     0       1/8/2015
234     0       1/15/2015
234     0       1/22/2015
```

Is there a way I can 'select distinct(Cust)' and join them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, generate the rows you want using a `cross join`.  Then bring in the data you want using a `left join`:

```
select c.cust, w.week, coalesce(t.sales, 0) as sales
from weeks w cross join
     (select distinct cust from t) c left join
     t
     on t.cust = c.cust and t.week = w.week;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `left join` on the dates table and use `isnull` on the sales column. Use an equivalent of `isnull` in Netezza.

```
select t1.cust, isnull(t1.sales,0), t2.week
from daystable2 t2 left join salestable1 t1 on t1.week = t2.week
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick

```
SELECT week, cust, COALESCE(sales, 0)
FROM week_tbl a LEFT JOIN cust_table b
ON a.week = b.week
```